# Efficient way to parse different lines of a text file

Tags: python, loops

I have a text file containing the data like this:

1  ---  1  ---  100

2  ---  1  ---  200

3  ---  1  ---  100

1  ---  2  ---  300

2  ---  2  ---  100

3  ---  2  ---  400

I want to extract the data of third column corresponding to different values of second column, for example add three numbers in third column corresponding to number 1 in second column and so on. I can loop though the text line by line, and find the third column in each line and add them. But that is not what I want. How should I do it efficiently in Python?

Comment: A data structure where? Is it a file, a list, ...?

Comment: What did you try and why did it not work. Edit your question and show us code.

Comment: @roganjosh It is part of a text file generated by a program.

Comment: So this is *text*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `itertools.groupby()`.

As an example, I'm using your exact *"data structure"* (a bunch of text in a stackoverflow question):

```
import itertools

data_structure = '''
1 --- 1 --- 100

2 --- 1 --- 200

3 --- 1 --- 100

1 --- 2 --- 300

2 --- 2 --- 100

3 --- 2 --- 400
'''.splitlines()

# create a key function able to extract the data you want to group:
def _key(line):
    return line.strip().split(' --- ')[1] # the 1 here means second column

#cleanup data:
clean_data = (line.strip() for line in data_structure if line.strip())

# then pass it to itertools.groupby:
for key, lines in itertools.groupby(clean_data, key=_key):
    print("Lines that contain number", key, 'in second column:')
    print(', '.join(lines))
```

The results:

```
Lines that contain number 1 in second column:
1 --- 1 --- 100, 2 --- 1 --- 200, 3 --- 1 --- 100
Lines that contain number 2 in second column:
1 --- 2 --- 300, 2 --- 2 --- 100, 3 --- 2 --- 400
```

EDIT: Now that you edited the question, and said you have  a text file, then you can just use it in place of `data_structure` and it will work:

```
data_structure = open('myfile.txt')
```

The rest of the code remains the same